# Convert standard C++ int to String^

Tags: c++-cli

I want to convert std::int to System::String^ in Visual C++/CLI enviroment. I know that we can use the library provided by Microsoft that include template function marshal_as

```
#include <msclr\marshal.h>

using namespace msclr::interop;

int count = 1;
String^ Apple;
Apple = marshal_as<String^>(count);
```

I couldn't run this statement as I got this error

```
'msclr::interop::error_reporting_helper<_To_Type,_From_Type,false>::marshal_as':
 This conversion is not supported by the library or the header file needed for 
this conversion is not included.
```

Comment: `String^` is not valid type in C++. Did you mean C++/CLI?

Comment: Yes C++/CLI. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int count = 100; 
System::String^ s = count.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`marshal_as` is used to convert between native types and their managed equivalents. It is NOT a general "convert anything to anything" tool. To convert an integer to a .NET `String`, you can use `std::to_string` to convert to a C++ string and then `marshal_as` to a `String`, or otherwise use `Int.ToString` if you want to do the conversion .NET-side.